# new redirect format in IIS

Tags: iis, vbscript, iis-7.5

A couple of months ago, I noted that some of my Classic ASP apps are redirecting in a strange way.
Where as previously a file would redirect from `page.asp` to `default.asp` (assuming the user was logged in - using a cookie), now, there redirect looks like
`domain.com/page.asp,default.asp`
which of course throws a 404 error, because that "page" (page.asp,default.asp) does not exist.

The redirects are usually done by using a `Response.Redirect`.

I also have a test to see if HTTPS in on - if not, there is an additional redirect, forwarding to the same page, but in HTTPS.

Is this a new config that needs to be done to prevent to change this redirect format?

Thanks

**UPDATES:**

**(1) This is the code i am using on the requested page, to make sure we have a valid cookie:**

```
if currentUserID = 0 then 
    conn.close
    set conn = nothing
    response.Redirect("default.asp")
end if
```

**(2) i have checked via localhost** as suggested by Vanquished Wombat - it seems like the redirect there does not happen. Maybe because SSL is not on for that?

**(3) Adding screenshot:** (see the line of 'requested URL')

[image]

Comment: There is no “new format”, if your redirects are not working either something has changed in the Classic ASP code or IIS UrlReWriting rules in the config are causing issues. Disable any rules then test the redirect.

Comment: does this format of `domain.com/default.asp,page.asp` rings any bells to you?

Comment: @Lankymart - do you think it is likely that the OP's server has had the IIS url-rewrite plugin installed and the OP is unaware ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat stranger things have happened.

Comment: Just to clarify - no one is making changes on the server. Not me (not a server guy) and not the host  - so anything that happened must have been pre installed or automatically updated/changed. Hence the question.

Comment: @kneidels thanks for confirming. So nothing has changed - no code changes, no windows updates? Sadly we all know things only go wrong when a change happens. Think the unthinkable, find the change and you'll find the answer.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat - i confirm i made no changes, but changes could definitely have come from Windows Updates - that's in fact what i am assuming, therefore asking if anyone knows about this format that came about, and how i can "fox" it (I am not a server person, but know my wau around a little)

Comment: @kneidels Just wanted to flush out the detail on changes. Could there be any proxies getting in the way? One way to check would be to RDP to server and access the web system via local URL and see what your redirects do.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, Good idea - will do

Comment: @VanquishedWombat - it seems like on `localhost` this issue does not exist. Could it be because of the SSL? I am also checking if they are accessing via `https`, and if not, adding an additional redirect to `https` mode. Also, updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: I am curious about the format you get, as in 'domain.com/page.asp,default.asp'. A comma list normally means the request included multiple values for the same key. Whilst that is interesting you need a solution. So going back to the start - are you in fact trying to force users into https when they initially connect via plain http? I ask because there are simple ways to achieve that with IIS that are more robust than an asp-script approach.

Comment: I like your practical outlook :-) when they come into the site, i first check SSL - even before i check if they have logged in. If not, i simply do a 301 redirect of the page to itself.  Only after, do i check the cookie for a login.

Comment: Are you using the 403.4 error redirect in IIS errors config?

Comment: Not that i know of. dont even know what that is

Answer (score 0):

Use can use module for IIS URL Rewrite
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there may be some confusion in how you are forcing users onto the SSL channel and this may be confusing the stats.

You can force users from HTTP to HTTPS using a custom error in IIS and a piece of Javascript. This will fire before your stat counters because IIS will reject the users request and send back the 403.4 custom error file, which in turn will revert them to the same basic URL but on the HTTPS protocol.

Save the following script as HTTPredirect.html in the root folder of the website, and follow the three step instructions.

```
<!-- beginning of HttpRedirect.htm file -->
<!--
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
' To force user to https port.
' 
' To make this work:
' 1. Put this html file in root of website in a file named HTTPredirect.html.
' 2. Go to IIS admin, click on the web site and open Error pages. 
' Set 403.4 error to static file with path = HTTPredirect.html
' 3. Still in IIS admin go to SSL setting and tick 'Require SSL' checkbox. Click Apply.
' Now it will work - redirecting all http urls to https.
'----------------------------------------------------------------
'
--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectToHttps()
{
var httpURL = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL  + window.location.hash;
var restOfUrl = window.location.href.substr(5);
window.location = "https:" + restOfUrl;
}
redirectToHttps();
</script>
<!-- end of HttpRedirect.htm file -->
```

You can also go 'hi-tech' and install IIS URL Rewrite which has a whole lot more capability but is overkill if you just need to switch users to HTTPS.

If this is not useful let me know and I will erase the answer.

Comment: Thanks!
After activating the 'Require SSL' option, browsing the site in `http` gave me this error on all pages `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`  Also - is the IIS URL Rewrite better than the JS Solution? For some reason i feel that the JS may not be full-proof, so maybe the IIS solution is better? Also want to be sure thay google sees the site as SSL

Comment: yes. using the initially checked box "insert content from static file...", which is located at: `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\SITE.COM\httpdocs\HTTPredirect.html`. the "try to return the error..." checkbox is not checked

Comment: Does your site have a public URL? And what version of IIS are you using, or what version of Windows?

Comment: I get this when I go to that website:
`<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://www.xxxxx.co.il/users/">here</a></body>` so something is afoot.